# SP2010 Custom State Machine Workflow using multiple Task Lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a state machine workflow that I created in VS2010 for SP2010.
I would like to have the WF utilize 2 different task lists.  One task list for tracking approvals and one task list for tracking assigned deliverables.  However, it seems like the workflowProperties.TaskList is locked down and I am unable to modify the task list "location" as the workflow progress from state to state.

Is it possible to have a custom workflow utilize multiple task lists?  How do I do it?

My main reason for doing it this way is that I want simplified status fields for my tasks.  On the approval task list the only status values will be Accepted, Rejected, Escalated, Pending.  While on my deliverable task list I would like the default choices of Not Started, In Progress, Complete, Waiting, Deferred. If there is a better way than using two different customized task lists, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I'm creating a static workflow machine.

It is possible to create a task by just adding an item to the list. I mean not using: `Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.CreateTask();`, but just add an `SPListItem` to an `SPLIst`.

The advantage is the you can add a task to every list on every site level. But is it possible to combine these task to an `OnTaskChanged()`? If not, is it a good idea to use an `EventReceiver` which triggers my forkflow steps?